# How to verify if my PC RAM is DDR2 or DDR3

Tags: memory, motherboard, ddr3, ddr2

I want to buy a memory expansion for my desktop computer, so I wanted to check if my motherboard supports DDR2 or DDR3. I did some tests for it, but got different results.

1. I ran `dmidecode` and got this result:

   ```
   type=DDR2
   speed=800Mhz
   ```
2. I saw the words in my mobo and there it clearly said **DDR3** near the slot.
3. I saw the specs of my mobo and it said:

   Memory:
   • 2 x DDR2 800/667 MHz SDRAM (8GB max.)
   • 2 x DDR3 1066/800/667 MHz SDRAM (4GB max.)

Another source of confusion is that I have 2 slots in my mobo, but the command shows 4, so I am totally confused about whether I have to buy DDR2 or DDR3 memory.

Comment: What is your make/model of your motherboard? There were some motherboard that supports DDR2 and DDR3. You can't mix them up in the same motherboard, but you can use 2 x DDR2 RAM, or 2 x DDR3 RAM, but not 1 x DDR2 and 1 x DDR3.

Comment: My motherboard is Mercury PIG41Z

Comment: More than likely it has different slots for ddr2 and ddr3, since the modules are not interchangeable.

Comment: But it has only 2 slots and my current module fits in both.

Comment: This is my mobo :www.mercury-pc.com/product-detail.php?link=p-mainboards&subtitle=Mainboard&productid=992

Comment: @Darius: What you said was right. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution. My Motherboard supports either 4GB of DDR3 or 8GB of DDR2. My currently installed one is DDR2 as said by `dmidecode`. I can't have one DDR2 and a DDR3. But I can have 2 of either of these.

Answer (score 3):

Run [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html), in the `memory` tab it shows the RAM type:

[image]

Comment: This only works on Windows.

Comment: next time, add linux tag to see that you need a linux software